# Flow do not report error when use undefined property in condition

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to check this code with Flow, which seems problematic for me:

```
// @flow

type Foo = {|
    foo: string
|}

function test(foo: Foo) {
    if (foo.bar) {
        console.log("WTF?")
    }
}
```

But Flow thinks differently. I'm very new to Flow, so I'm not sure where is the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Flow isn't going to check your conditional. [But if you were to add](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeAPoqNaJAQFygDOKATgJYB2A5ouQL7JIAV04BjFO1idQKLCwAUdWI3ywAlGSo12kUEoIA6AEYBDVptLaaNMdKaxoWQ3G4KARAHUAKrgD87urWoIKCqPIoCqSgZqyMbMI4-OpAA):

```
test({ bar: true })
```

It will check that and let you know that your argument is invalid. That's where it helps. You could potentially do anything in your function you want. It doesn't care. You are writing it. But it will stop you from using something that is annotated incorrectly.

Think about it this way. `Foo` is describing what is expected. So inside your function, you may still want a check for `foo.bar` even though it doesn't meet the expectation. But flow will tell you when you attempt to use it that you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Actually, in my real usage, I have boolean flags which turn on and off some functionality. Now if I misspell one of flags Flow doesn't help me to catch it. Very un-useful. Switched to TypeScript instead.

Answer (score 1):

> In Flow, it is considered safe to pass an object with extra properties where a normal object type is expected.
>
> This is because of “[width subtyping](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/width-subtyping/)”.
>
> Sometimes it is useful to disable this behavior and only allow a specific set of properties. For this, Flow supports “exact” object types.

```
type Foo = {|
    foo: string
|}
```

is an [exact object type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types), so that it is not allowable to pass extra property `bar`

Hope it helps you to understand more about why

```
type Foo = {
    foo: string
}
```

solves your problem.

Comment: Exact and not exact object type makes no difference in my case

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your example behaves as you expected in current Flow version (0.83.0) and since 0.68.0:

https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeAPoqNaJAQFygDOKATgJYB2A5ouQL7JIAV04BjFO1idQKLCwAUdWI3ywAlGSo12kUEoIA6AEYBDVptLaaNMdKaxoWQ3G4KARAHUAKrgD87urWoIL8QA

[image: Flow Try]

... which means this use case was not working when you created the question, but got implemented in march 2018 ...